# Function for searching via vlookup in closed workbook is not working

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, excel-4.0

I try to do a `Vlookup` in a closed workbook via `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. Since I need to find a lot of values in different workbooks it makes sense to do it in a closed workbook.

I used the below code, but it doesn't work if I enter the function on my Excel book:

```
=GetVlookup("D:", "testfile.xls", "Sheet1", "C1:D8", 2, "CDM-01_10")
```

I can assure that there is a file on my `D:` named `testfile.xls` with a `sheet1` and content in the range I mention here. But result is `#value!`.

I want this in a function since I want to make a price calculation add-in that can be used in several workbooks, so I rather haven't introduced this in a macro.

```
Public Function GetVlookup(path, file, sheet, ref, Col, vVal)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook

    Dim arg As String

'   Make sure the file exists

If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"

If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
    GetVlookup = "File Not Found"
    Exit Function
End If

If IsNumeric(vVal) Then
  vVal = CDbl(vVal)
Else
  vVal = Chr(34) & vVal & Chr(34)
  End If

' Create the argument
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Address(, , xlR1C1)
' Execute an XLM macro
GetVlookup = ExecuteExcel4Macro("Vlookup(" & vVal & "," & arg & "," & Col & ",0)")
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome! Are you getting an error? Where? And where on drive D is this file? (which folder). Hold the [Windows] key and push [R] to get the Run box, and type `d:\testfile.xls` and hit [Enter]. If it doesn't open your file, then you're not specifying the correct location.

Comment: Why are you specifying `xlR1C1`?

Comment: The file opens, so the location is correct. If I use =VLOOKUP("CDM-01_10",[testfile.xls]sheet1!$C$1:$D$8,2,FALSE) in my book (so not via function) it's going well as well

Comment: About xlR1C1: I read that you need to do it that way if you use executeexcel4macro. I tried with ".address(,,xlA1)" but this gives the same error

Comment: Hello, nobody who can help me?